# I want to add a field card to the to do table I created with .Net, but I don't know exactly where I went wrong

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, dom

#### Html

My goal is to add a dom element by rotating the javascript with this add html element button. When you click to add, the modal opens and after the necessary inputs are filled, a card needs to be added to the table by saying add, but there is something wrong and I could not figure out what happened.I would like to state that I have investigated the problem.

```
<h5 class="card-title">Upcoming</h5>
    <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">Upcoming Task</h6>
    <!--Table title.-->
</div>
<!--Card body.-->
<div class="card-body p-3">

    <div id="tasks-upcoming">



        <!--Card Head.-->
        <div class="card mb-3 bg-light cursor-grab border drag-1" id="1">
            <div class="card-body p-3">
                <!--Check Box-->
                <div class="float-end mr-n2">
                    <label class="form-check">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" aria-label="completed" checked="">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <!--Check Box-->
                <!--Work title-->
                <p id="worktitle">Mobile Application</p>
                <!--Work title-->
                <!--Avatar-->
                <div class="float-end mt-n1">
                    <img id="userName" src="../images/DefaultUser-50.png" width="32" height="32" class="rounded-circle" alt="Avatar">
                </div>
                <!--Avatar-->
                <a id="workShow" class="ist-group-item active waves-effect btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalLong">Show</a>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

### JavaScript

Here I tried to do the operations I mentioned by calling the element IDs.

```
//Add to-do card function.
 $(document).ready(function () {
        classnames();
        //call dragula
    
        dragula([
            document.getElementById('tasks-upcoming'),
            document.getElementById('tasks-progress'),
            document.getElementById('tasks-completed'),
            document.getElementById('skill')
        ]).on('drop', function (el) {
            //change classes depending on column.
            classnames();
        });
    
    
        //static adding of values
    
        $(".submit").click(function () {
            var getvalue1 = document.getElementById("taskName"), //task titile.
                getvalue2 = document.getElementById("informationText"), //task information.
    
                getvalue3 = document.getElementById("skill") //personal.
            
                getvalue4 = document.getElementById("textBody"), //to-do text modal.
    
                a = getvalue1.value,
                b = getvalue2.value,
                c = getvalue3.value,
                d = getvalue4.value;
    
            var today = new Date();
            $(".drag-1").append("<div class='card mb-3 bg-light cursor-grab border drag-1'><div class='card-body p-3'><input type='checkbox'arial-label='completed' checked='' class='checkbox' name='' value=''/><p id='workTitle1'><a id='workInfo'>" + a + "<p  id='worktitle'></p>" + b + "<img id='userName' width='32' height='32' class='rounded - circle' alt'=P-'>" + c + "<a id='workShow'>" + d + "<div id='textBody' class='modal-body'></a></div></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is incomplete and so no one will be able replicate your problem and help you with a solution. classnames(); function is missing and there is no element with class="submit"

Apart from that, there are several errors that needs fixing:

This line...

```
$(".drag-1").append("<div class='card mb-3 bg-light cursor-grab border drag-1'><div class='card-body p-3'><input type='checkbox'arial-label='completed' checked='' class='checkbox' name='' value=''/><p id='workTitle1'><a id='workInfo'>" + a + "<p  id='worktitle'></p>" + b + "<img id='userName' width='32' height='32' class='rounded - circle' alt'=P-'>" + c + "<a id='workShow'>" + d + "<div id='textBody' class='modal-body'></a></div></div>');
```

should end with double quote not single quote.

This line:

```
getvalue3 = document.getElementById("skill") //personal.
```

is missing a comma.

It is currently missing the following at the very end:

```
});});
```

I suspect you've only copied so much code as to why this is missing. I've only pointed it out just in case it really is missing.

These are the obvious problems that need addressing. You will need to supply more code if this is still problematic.